# Searching for specific string in a file

Tags: string, powershell, pattern-matching, conditional-statements

I need to find this pattern, `"LogEntry="`, across multiple lines  in the following file:
C:\test.conf

And change the line to read: `"LogEntry=&amp;MAC="` instead.

The script works fine so far to do that, but if someone runs the script twice it will re-add the same pattern, doubling it up.

I need to find a way to put a check in place to know if the file already has that pattern in it. Could someone please give me a hand with this one ?

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead in your regex e.g.:

```
'LogEntry=(?!&amp;MAC=)'
```

That regex will not match the already modified line.  Read more about [look ahead/behind zero length assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

BTW if you have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com), you can do this edit operatio with a single command:

```
Edit-File C:\test.conf -Pattern 'LogEntry=(?!&amp;MAC=)' -Replace 'LogEntry=&amp;MAC='
```

And if you can't use PSCX's Edit-File, here is roughly the equivalent:

```
$content = Get-Content C:\test.temp
$content | Foreach {$_ -replace 'LogEntry=(?!&amp;MAC=)','LogEntry=&amp;MAC='} | Out-File -Encoding ASCII
```

I don't know what the file encoding is for your file.  You need to know that and use the appropriate encoding on the `Out-File` command. If you don't specify the encoding, it defaults to Unicode.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Let me try this out right now and I will let know if that worked.

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force

$path = "C:\test.temp"
$word = "LogEntry="
$replacement = "LogEntry=&amp;MAC="
$regex = 'LogEntry=(?!&amp;MAC=)'
$text = get-content $path 

foreach ($_ in $text)
{
 if ($_ -notmatch $regex) 
{
   $newText = $text -replace $word, $replacement
   $newText > $path
   }
 }

Now its not doing anything to the file but I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: See the updated answer.  And try this in a PowerShell console that already has the execution policy set to Unrestricted (try to eliminate some variables).

Comment: Keith, I was able to successfully replace the string. My main issue is that I need a check in place to see if this script has already modified the string.

Comment: `if (Select-String 'LogEntry=(?!&amp;MAC=)' C:\test.conf -Quiet) { ... }` - this test returns true if there is one or more LogEntry that has not been converted.

Comment: Thank you Keith! That logic worked, Sir. Thanks again!

Comment: Keith, -Encoding ASCII was very important as the file looked identical in WinMerge but exactly as you said encoding was different and XML parsing did not like it. Thank you again!